# What is the C# ThreadPool join using QueueUserWorkItem?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code snippet using QueueUserWorkItem. How do I implement join method such that I can make sure the thread I spawned completed before executing `Y` statement below

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(TestHelper.MoveFromAtoB), new System.Tuple<string, string>(srcNode, destNode));
// start the copy


// do operation X
X();  // this will run in parallel with the above

// Join threads. I want to make sure at this point we block until TestHelper.MoveFromAtoB is done execution.

// run Y()
Y();
```

Comment: Use an AutoResetEvent.  Your TestHelper.MoveFromAtoB() method must call its Set() method when it is done, add the WaitOne() method to your snippet.

Comment: @HansPassant could you post an example how to do that please?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use another construct that you can wait for?

Comment: Why not to switch to TPL and use `Task.Run` instead of using `ThreadPool` directly?

Comment: @PetSerAl I am trying that now instead. I think you have a point, it could be better model for I want to achieve. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I used delegate inside Queue Work item. To make sure it waits and join the call.